# Навешивание плагина на динамически создаваемый контент js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let content = `<div id="img_preview"></div>`;    
$(".popup").html(content);

// это не работает тк #img_preview не существует при загрузке страницы
// плагин по обрезанию фото на jquery
 $('#img_preview').cropper({
                viewMode: 3, 
                // ещё свойства      
 });
```

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: перемести вызов `$('#img_preview').cropper` внутрь _showPopup_ после `$(".popup").html`

Comment: Кроме того непонятно: приведенный код это цельный кусок кода, или данные строки между собой не связаны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяем если элемент был изменен только потом вызываем кроппер

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".popup", function() {
    $('#img_preview').cropper({
                viewMode: 3, 
                // ещё свойства      
    });
 });
```

Comment: при большом количестве элементов и частых изменениях не лучшее решение

Comment: А можно более детально?

Answer (score 0):

возможно пред идущий ответ правильный не успел проверить. сам нашел вот такую реализацию  прописывается в html, после перемещается в нужное место при помощи $('.pop-up').append($('#img_preview')), таким образом элемент присутствует при загрузке страницы всегда.
(заранее извиняюсь за манеру изложения, всегда были с этим проблемы)

Comment: почему просто не инициализировать плагин после добавления элемента? зачем его при загрузке страницы пытаться вызывать?

Comment: Можно тогда защитать правельный ответ, на поставленый вопрос?